# Git deleted files sticking around. How do i get a clean working directory?

Tags: git

So I'm refactoring my views in haml in a separate haml branch.
I accidentally removed my new haml views instead of old erb views.

```
$ git rm app/views/projects/edit.html.haml app/views/projects/new.html.haml .....
```

So I did a reset

```
$ git reset HEAD app/views/projects/edit.html.haml app/views/projects/new.html.haml .....
Unstaged changes after reset:
D   app/views/projects/_form.html.erb
D   app/views/projects/edit.html.erb
D   app/views/projects/edit.html.haml
.
.
.
```

git status shows

```
$ git status
# On branch haml
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   deleted:    app/views/projects/_form.html.erb
#   deleted:    app/views/projects/edit.html.erb
#   deleted:    app/views/projects/edit.html.haml
.
.
.
```

Where do I go from here in order to keep the haml files only and get a clean working directory?

Im sure its simple but would rather ask than make it worse. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a `reset --hard`, which will update the working directory.

Comment: perfect, thanks. I was worried about --hard initially when I did the reset but makes sense now.